# Remove whitespace inside HTML tags

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I am currently working on translating a big data set (about 7000 lines). This dataset, containing English phrases but also HTML tags, has been translated to Dutch using Google Translate.

However, when reviewing the generated translation, Google Translate also scrambled the HTML tags by adding spaces. I would like to remove all invalid whitespace inside HTML tags in the translated file. For example:

```
this is a test. < a href = "hello.php" >test</ a>;
```

should become:

```
this is a test. <a href="hello.php">test</a>;
```

Is there a regular expression that can make this possible?

Comment: You don't want to remove _all_ whitespace, you want to remove extra space around `=` and before `>`.

Comment: `$yourString = str_replace("< ", "<", $yourString);`, Repeat?

Comment: Use HTML Tidy to "fix up" the markup. http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: @Bobby i guess that should work.. but it will be really heavy on the system performance wise.

Comment: @Michael: True, I've edited my question to improve. I know of Tidy - but only in an output sense. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Bobby That is not an acceptable solution - it wouldn't work for the closing tag and it would be a resource hog. I would rather see a regular expression.

Comment: @SanderSmolenaers: The suggestions here are quickly done. Lenghtier, it's an request that you show what you done so far to solve the problem and ask more specifically about the issues on the way to solve that. Just putting your requirements here is not really acccepted. That's why you see downvotes as well.

Comment: @hakre Thank you. I've clarified the context.

Comment: @Destralak: Tell the google translate "API" that your input is HTML and you want to keep it preserved. – And if you post your code how you call google translate, others might be able to show you how you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = str_replace("< ", "<", $text);
$text = str_replace("> ", ">", $text);
$text = str_replace(" <", "<", $text);
$text = str_replace(" >", ">", $text);
$text = str_replace("= ", "=", $text);
$text = str_replace(" =", "=", $text);
$text = str_replace("\/ ", "\/", $text);
```